# How to hide stripe secret key in Angular5 project

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, stripe.js

To my understanding, while i read the stripe docs i have to put my stripe public key in my index.html file and when going into production i should put in my stripe secret key, the problem is when the project is viewed in my browser i can easily get the key.
My question, is there a better way to hide this from view or probably not put it directly in my index.html file

Comment: This question is incorrectly quoting Stripe documentation and using incorrect terms.  See https://stripe.com/docs/keys

Stripe provides you with a "publishable key" which can be safely used publicly.  Whereas, the "secret key" can only be used on your own server.

When you go to production, instead of using your "test" keys, you use your set of "live" keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this [article](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2016/02/15/securing-api-keys-in-a-javascript-single-page-app/) explains, is not possible to hide an API key in a client-side app.

Your best shot is to reorganise your app to make the call server-side and pass the result to the client from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, Stripe contains a *test* and *live* mode.

Each of these have a *publishable* and *secret* key pair.

So in production (live), you can safely publish your *pk_live_xxxxxx* in your JavaScript code.

TL;DR

Your secret key should be stored on your own server to be kept confidential.

Also it should be kept out of version control to be safe, such as in an environment variable in a separate file.